# Can not start mysql on linux

Tags: mysql, linux

When I tried to restart mysql after I restarted Linux server,
I got in trouble, I am not able to start mysql It is responding `Job failed to start`

here is error log

```
170225  0:46:41 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead    of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a  future release. Please use the full name instead.
170225  0:46:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Aborting
170225  0:46:41 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170225  0:46:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170225  0:46:41 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170225  0:46:41 [ERROR] Aborting
```

thx for your help

Comment: duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the option "skip-innodb" was uncommented on configuration file my.cnf. If that's the case, comment the line again. If you don't want to use INNODB, you must modify your tables to use another table format, as MyISAM p.e.